PrimeNG Table: Virtual scrolling with frozen columns doesn't scroll up
PrimeNG table with virtual scroll and frozen columns (1 or more) doesn't scroll up if you are at the bottom of the table. The scroll bar keeps jumping up and down and the table is always at the last row.
The scroll does not work correctly.
What I found out is that it works with <= 35 rows. With a >36 rows dataset the scrolling does no longer work as described before.
Example on StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mdzxe4-a3m2x6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-virtual-scroll-demo.html
Also found following GitHub issue:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/16432
Is there a solution to the error or a temporary workaround?

Found a workaround what works:
https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/353#discussioncomment-11320298
The Bug is reported.
